# Spring integration - incoming mails handling

Tags: spring-integration

I have very simple class with spring integration flow for incoming mails as follows:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow imapMailFlow(Receiver receiver) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imaps://usr:pass@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(3000)))
            .handle(receiver)
            .get();
}

@Component
public class Receiver implements GenericHandler<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object handle(Object message, MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
        //sout message
        return null;
    }
}
```

Handle method does not... handle incoming mails, I see only: 
attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]

Comment: Set `mail.debug=true` in the `javaMailProperties` to see the interactions with the server.

Comment: I've already done that, I saw that it reads messages from inbox.

Comment: So why don't you edit your question to show that log? Turn on DEBUG logging for Spring classes to figure out what's happening.